# PHP shell_exec - some shell commands not available

Tags: php, bash, shell, command-line-interface, shell-exec

before starting - I have seen some SO similar questions, but tbh I got even more lost.

I am trying to run `nvm use` and `nvm -v` within the PHP `shell_execute`, but am constantly getting the following error:

```
sh: nvm: command not found
```

It seems like PHP is using **Bourne shell** where nvm is not available.
I am mostly using **Bash** in Terminal where everything is fine (in other shells like ZSH I get the same error).

**Questions:**

How can I make PHP run commands with `shell_exec` (if there is alternative I am open for considering it) I usually use in Bash?

**Extra notes (maybe helpful):**

1. This command is only used on a local environment so changing settings on dev machine is  something I am open to consider. (would be good to support Mac/Win and Linux, but Mac is the main focus at the moment).
2. If I run `which nvm` in the *bash* I get nothing in the terminal.
3. NVM was installed with Brew (don't know if that has any impact)

**The usecase:**

I am building a WP CLI toolkit where one of the commands is `wp custom install`. The command should switch to the right Node.js version of the project, install npm and php dependencies as well as some extra things.

```
// basic code sample
namespace Custom/CustomCli;

class CustomCli {

    public static function init(){
    
        if( !(defined('WP_CLI') && WP_CLI) ) return;
        \WP_CLI::add_command( 'custom', '\Custom\CustomCli' );

    }
    
    /*
    * If the Node.js version !== to .nvmrc try 'nvm use'
    * after correct version is selected run 'npm install'
    * also run 'composer install' and 'composer dump-autoload'
    */
    public function install( $args ){
        \WP_CLI::log( shell_exec('nvm -v') ); # once I figure out this I guess I'll know how to fully handle installation
    }

}

CustomCli::init();
```

Comment: I would take a look at the function of the variable `PATH`.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for the reply. NVM is added in the .bash_profile. You mean to add it to $PATH? Like `export PATH=$PATH:~/.nvm`

My .bash_profile: 
`
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
`

Comment: One cannot use commands, which are installed for another user.